# Conversion of MySQL binary GEOMETRY fields in PHP

Tags: php, geospatial, mysql-spatial

I’m working on an application integrating mapquest maps and using the mapquest API.

At this moment I want to achieve the following: the registered user has to input latitude and longitude information, and in the database this information has to be stored as geometry type field. Conversely, a user looking at their account should see the latitude and longitude information that was entered.

In an earlier simplified codebase I achieved this directly in the MySQL query, by using the MySQL functions `AsText` and `GeomFromText`. But now I’m on CodeIgniter and need to do the conversion in PHP

Is there anything equivalent in PHP to MySQL's `AsText` and `GeomFromText` functions?

Answer (score 10):

It appears that the `PHP` `unpack` function is what is needed to extract the coordinate information.

`MySQL` stores the geometry fields in the WKB (Well Known Binary) format. The `unpack` function is able to extract that information when provided the proper format specifier. The following code is from a test script which successfully extracted the desired information.

Please note that my `format` for unpack differs slightly from that of the reference.  This is because the WKB string wasn't retrieved from MySQL with the `AsWKB()` function, so it [contains extra padding](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69798).

```
<?php
    $padding = 0;
    $order   = 1;
    $gtype   = 1;
    $lon     = -73.91353;
    $lat     = 42.80611;

    $bindata = pack('LcLd2', $padding, $order, $gtype, $lat, $lon);

    printf("Packed: %s\n\n", bin2hex($bindata));

    $result = unpack('Lpadding/corder/Lgtype/dlatitude/dlongitude', $bindata);
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

References [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-wkb-format) and [ESRI Network](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.0/general_topics/wkb_representation.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I, too, am trying to extract geometry field data.I am using the `MySQLi` class to retrieve rows of data and display it according to field type.

While I haven't yet figured out how to decode the geometry field data, I can view it by using the `bin2hex` function.  A point stored using `GeomFromText('POINT(-73.91353 42.80611)')`
using `bin2hex` gives me a 50 character string value of

```
0000000001010000008d7a8846777a52c0417dcb9c2e674540
```

A partial list of field type numbers can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php).

I hope that this helps you!  If I discover more, I'll pass it on here.

Comment: One of @JoeJ's answers is redundant, probably this one, and should be deleted and the good bits edited into the other answer.