# Overriding Laravel Model View

Tags: laravel, eloquent, overriding, mysql-spatial

I'm attempting to handle map marker locations as natively as possible using MySQL spatial data types.  I don't want to resort to additional columns for `lat` and `lng,` as eventually, I want to be able to encode lines and polygons (and other geometries) as well.  The table has a `point` column type:

```php
Schema::create('maps', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->point('map_center')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

On the view side, Eloquent is a little dumber than I imagined it would be, given the built-in support for creating these spatial types in the database.  If I `get()` a model, `map_center` displays the raw encoded geometry.

```
>>> $map=Map::first()
=> App\Map {#2935
     id: 1,
     map_center: b"\0\0\0\0\x01\x01\0\0\0ºõš\x1E\x14\x7FRÀb0\x7F…Ì_D@",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
   }
```

I wrote a `center()` method that returns an object containing lat and long:

```php
public function center()
{
    if ($this->map_center) 
    {
        $result = DB::select('
            select ST_Y(map_center) as lat, ST_X(map_center) as lng 
            from maps 
            where id = :id
        ', 
        ['id' => $this->id]);
        $center['lat'] = $result[0]->lat;
        $center['lng'] = $result[0]->lng;
        return (object) $center;
    }
    else
    {
        dd($this);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
>>> $map->center()->lat
=> 40.748429
```

This is a decent workaround, but slightly ugly.  Instead, I want Eloquent to extract that so that the model returns a human readable coordinate, something like:

```
>>> $map=Map::first()
=> App\Map {#2935
     id: 1,
     map_center: {
       lat: 40.748429,   // or X: and Y:
       lng: -73.985603, 
     }
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
   }
```

Given that it's a `point` type (with two components), is it possible to automatically retrieve the data using `ST_AsText(p)` or an object containing `ST_X(p)` and `ST_Y(p)`?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL stores the data as WKB (Well Known Binary) format.

Take a look at here [Conversion of MySQL binary GEOMETRY fields in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027025/conversion-of-mysql-binary-geometry-fields-in-php)

You can use a [Model Attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). It should be something like this.

```
public function getMapCenterAttribute()
{
    $center = unpack('Lpadding/corder/Lgtype/dlatitude/dlongitude', $this->map_center);
    return $center;
}
```

You should also have something similar for `setMapCenterAttribute` doing it in reverse using `pack` function if required.

Comment: so this is basically intercepting the display of the data *after* it's been retrieved from the database.  is it possible to intercept how the data is retrieved from the database itself?  i.e. automatically wrapping spatial types with an ST_AsText() or ST_AsGeoJSON() or similar?

Comment: You can look into scopes. It can get a bit hairy but take a look at these places.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes and https://theokouzelis.com/php/laravel-eloquent-calculated-fields.html